# Last index of an associative array

Tags: php

Is there a simple way to get the last index of an associative array?

The array which I want to know the index has the following structure:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [x] => 35
        [y] => 28
        [z] => 10
        [e] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [x] => 52.5
        [y] => 42
        [z] => 15
        [e] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [x] => 69.65
        [y] => 54.95
        [z] => 20
        [e] => 0
    )

)
```

Atm it has 3 entries, but it can have between 1 and 366. What I need from this is either get the last index of the array (and add 1 to it) or get the last value of `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
$cnt = count($my_array);
echo $my_array[$cnt-1]['id'];
```

You can also use [**end**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) like

```
$end_arr = end($my_array);
echo $end_arr['id'];
```

You can also do it with [**array_slice**](https://www.php.net/array_slice) like

```
$end_arr = array_slice($my_array, -1, 1, true); 
echo $end_arr['id'];
```

Comment: More easily you can add `+1` to `count()` as his `id` is one more than last array key

Comment: He is saying ` What I need from this is either get the last index of the array (and add 1 to it) or get the last value of id`. means he want to get the last `id` and to that id he wants to add `1`

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Cheers.

Comment: see the example given the first array index was `0` and `id` value is `1` , the second array index was `1` and `id` value is `2` and the last array index was `2` and `id` value is `3`. so you can add `+1 ` to `count()` instead of fetching array value

Comment: `Is there a simple way to get the last index of an associative array`..see the part `associative array`.we cont predict for the same here right?

Comment: but in this case as OP mentioned it is going follow strictly the same pattern, because at the last he mentioned What I need from this is either get **the last index of the array (and add 1 to it)** or get the last value of id

Comment: I asked for both ways because the `id` is an a.i. value, so it is linked to index as a +1 value, so, and for the purposes of my program, I need either the index of the last elemnet (and therefore need to add 1) or the value of the `id` of the last element (and don't need to add 1 there). The second way @Gautam3164 indicated works exactly like I wanted.

Comment: @Comum both works same and gives you desired o/p. What i am talking is something about efficiency. instead of getting value from two step you can get value in single step. **But beware the idea i proposed will work only for the scenario you mention and arrays follow strictly the same pattern in the scenario. It will not work for all the cases.**

Comment: And by the way i have to alter one thing in my idea proposed. You dont need to add `+1` to `count()`, the value of last `id` is value of `count()` itself

Comment: @krishna cool dude.lets this stop this discussion.And if you want to propose any idea just include it as answer.It may helpful for the future users

Comment: lol, you have covered all the possible ways to find solution in your answer. So i just want to .... Ok as you said lets stop this discussion. this can turn out to be never ending discussion. In simple my idea was neither good enough to be an answer nor to be neglected.So let it hang around as an extra note.Bye. :)

Answer (score 2):

try with `end()`. It returns the value of the last element or FALSE for empty array. -

```
$last = end($yourArray);
$newId = $last['id']; //the last id
```

Comment: ypu.. just few seconds late... :)

Comment: Dude you also deserve it.Few seconds not matter ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$key_arrays = array_keys($your_array);//gives you all key values
$max_id = max($key_arrays);// finds the maximum value in it
$last_id = $your_array[$max_id][id]; // and you id as your request
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.